# Is there a way to call M-x my-org-babel-block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a named org-babel source block like this:

```
#+NAME: my-org-babel-block
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(print org-babel-load-languages)
#+END_SRC
```

**Is there any way to call this block with `M-x my-org-babel-block`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can do something like this:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun my-org-babel-block ()
    (interactive)
    (org-sbe "my-org-babel-block"))
#+end_src
```

defining a *command* (i.e. a function with an `interactive` spec) that executes the block with the given name. You can now call the command with `M-x my-org-babel-block` which will use `org-sbe` to execute the block.

The doc string of `org-sbe` (which you can get with `C-h f org-sbe RET`) says in part:

> org-sbe is a Lisp macro in ‘ob-table.el’.
>
> (org-sbe SOURCE-BLOCK &rest VARIABLES)
>
> Return the results of calling SOURCE-BLOCK with VARIABLES.
>
> Each element of VARIABLES should be a list of two elements: the
> first element is the name of the variable and second element is a
> string of its value.

Comment: Does this work with other languages than emacs lisp?

Comment: Yes: `org-sbe` executes a code block - it doesn't care what language the code block is in.

Comment: Right, you're evaluating the emacs-lisp block there and it refers to the other block named `my-org-babel-block`.

Comment: With this, I have to define one function per named block. Is it possible to define a function that does this for *all* named blocks in the file?

Comment: Yes, but that is a different question which you should ask separately. And when you do, specify what you mean for the function to do: I can think of two different interpretations of the question.

Comment: OK, here is the [next question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62158/20629).