# org-babel: define commands for all named source blocks in given set of files

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62156/20629) shows how to define a command that executes a named org-babel source block. If you want to do this for all named source blocks in a file, you could define one command per block. That's cumbersome.

**I'm looking for a function that defines commands for *all* named blocks in a given set of files**.

- the function should be placed in `init.el` to define commands for all named source blocks in
  a set of files
- the command names should prefix something like 'my-org-babel-' to all block names
- in case of duplicate block names, the latest one encountered can be retained

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to do almost (but not quite) everything you want. The following two functions are to be added to your init file:

```el
(defun my-org-babel-make-func (name)
   "Construct a string defining the function, then parse the
   string into a Lisp s-expression and eval that to actually
   define the function."
   (let ((s (format "(defun my-org-babel-%s () (interactive) (org-sbe \"%s\"))"
             name name)))
      (eval (read s))))

(defun my-org-babel-function-maker(filename)
   "Map the form over all the code blocks in the file. The form
   gets the name of the block and if non-nil, calls the make-func function
   to define the function for that name."
   (org-babel-map-src-blocks filename
     (let ((name (plist-get (cadr (org-element-at-point)) :name)))
        (when name
           (my-org-babel-make-func name))))
      nil)
```

I hope the comments are enough to convey what the functions are doing.

Then if you have an Org mode file `foo.org` with named code blocks like this:

```org
* foo

  #+name: hello
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
  "Hello"
  #+end_src

  #+name: good-bye
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
  "Good Bye"
  #+end_src
```

you can execute `(my-org-babel-function-maker "foo.org")` and then you should have commands `my-org-babel-hello` and `my-org-babel-good-bye` that you can execute with `M-x my-org-babel-hello` or `M-x my-org-babel-good-bye`.

If you want this to be done when you open the file you can use a [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) block to execute the function maker when the file is opened:

```org
... named code blocks as above ...

* COMMENT Local variables

  # Local variables:
  # eval: (my-org-babel-function-maker (buffer-file-name))
  # End:
```

Caveats:

- no error checking
- blocks with duplicate names are not handled the way you want: `org-sbe` will execute the named code block - if there is more than one code block with that name, it will run whichever one *it* wants: which one that is depends on the implementation of `org-sbe` and is outside the scope of this answer. I would suggest you avoid blocks with the same name in the file.
- it would be nice if these functions were defined locally for this file
  only, but that's not the way it works: functions are global in scope in Emacs Lisp, so `my-org-babel-hello` will exist everywhere. If you execute it in a different file that has a code block named `hello`, it will happily run that code block; and if there is no such code block, it will complain.